# How to encode comma in Spring UriComponentsBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

I have following code:

```
    String convertedBuilder = builder.toUriString();
    convertedBuilder = convertedBuilder.replace(",", "\\,");



    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(convertedBuilder)
              .build().toUri();
```

The idea is to replace a single comma `','` by a `'\,'` (slash and comma).
Originated URL should be something like

`'server-url'?name=te%5C%2Cst` for parameter value `'te\,st`.

However Spring generates this one:

```
'server-url'?name=te%5C%252Cst
```

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Comment: Why do you want to encode the `,`? With `.build(false)` you can tell the `UriComponentsBuilder` that it's not encoded. It will encode `\` to `%5C`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, it's an URL exposed by a Salesforce endpoint and I have to send to them as '%5C%2C'

Comment: What is value of `convertedBuilder` before the replace? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because I don't see `,` being encoded as anything, using code in question.

Comment: @Andreas **https://xxxxxx/services/apexrest/EnterpriseObjects/serviceAccount?name=te,st** is the convertedBuilder string.

Comment: *Unable to reproduce:* When I run that code, using the value you just gave, I get `https://xxxxxx/services/apexrest/EnterpriseObjects/serviceAccount?name=te%5C,st`, i.e. no encoding of `,`, when using `spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar`.

Comment: Yes correct! @Andreas I got what you've got, I would like now how to have **https://xxxxxx/services/apexrest/EnterpriseObjects/serviceAccount?name=te%5C%2Cst** instead of **https://xxxxxx/services/apexrest/EnterpriseObjects/serviceAccount?name=te%5C,st**

Comment: `URI uri = URI.create(convertedBuilder.replace(",", "%5C%2C"));`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement where I had to call a service with a GPS coordinate like this:

```
http://example.com/path?param1=40.678806%2C-73.943244
```

`UriComponentsBuilder` alone would either:

- not encode the `,` (comma) within the parameter value
- encode the encoded comma if I already had encoded the parameter with `URLEncoder`, thus producing the value `40.678806%252C-73.943244`

I resolved by explicitly encoding the query parameter with `URLEncoder` and telling `UriComponentsBuilder` that the URL was already encoded:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com/path")
        .queryParam("param1" , URLEncoder.encode("40.678806,-73.943244", "UTF-8"));

ResponseEntity<String> resp = template.exchange(
        builder.build(true).toUri(),
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String> () {}
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to encode comma in Spring UriComponentsBuilder?

UriComponentsBuilder doesn't encode the comma since RFC doesn't require it to be encoded. You will have to encode it manually as suggested by Andreas in the comments.

> However Spring generates this one:
>   'server-url'?name=te%5C%252Cst

No, it doesn't, as also mentioned by Andreas. It encodes the backslash but not the comma. Please fix the question if you need any more information.